# Actualización de base de datos offline

Tags: c#, mysql

Tengo una base de datos de lado de un servidor web y la manipulo desde workbech, pero cuando pierdo la señal de internet mi aplicación por lógica deja de mandar datos a la base de datos.

La pregunta es:

¿Si creo una base de datos idéntica pero de forma local podria mandar los datos cuando no tenga internet a la base local y cuando regrese la señal de internet mande la bd local los nuevos datos ingresados a la base de datos del servidor?

¿O saben alguna otra forma que la aplicación pueda seguir trabajando offline y cuando regrese la señal de Internet, pueda actualizar los cambios?

Comment: hermano sin las mayúsculas por favor...

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento, ya realizaste alguna investigación previa. Te dejo los siguientes enlaces para que mejores tu pregunta. Evita los negativos e incluso el cierre de tu pregunta. [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878). De paso Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Lo que buscas puedes lograrlo usando [replicación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replicaci%C3%B3n_(inform%C3%A1tica)). No es un tema básico sino mas bien avanzado. Debes documentarte bien al respecto. Saludos

Comment: Este escenario que comentas es muy habitual en caso de los moviles. Lo que hay que hacer es lo siguiente: 1. Creas dos bases de datos iguales. 2. Tu codigo solo trabaja con base de datos local. 3. Creas otro hilo en parlelo que va revisando conexion con BD externa. En caso que haya conexion, sincronizas manualmente los datos en las tablas. Para ello los registros tienen campos normalmente adicionales: version (tipo float), fecha actualización (tipo timestamp), fuente de creación (tipo string). 4. Teniendo estos datos consultas los datos entre dos bases de datos, una vez sincronizados los datos